# Portalocker Redislock: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, redis, locking

I am using the Python package Portalocker to create a Redis lock:

```
import portalocker

lock = portalocker.RedisLock("some_lock_channel_name")

with lock:
    print("do something here")
```

However, this gives me the following error:

`redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting to localhost:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I have no idea where to start to fix this. The portalocker documentation is rather limited (https://portalocker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis-locks).

Is there some step I am missing?